# Add IP limitation at Google Translation API

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

How can I limit the access to the Google Translation API to only a specific IP, the IP of my server? Because someone else is using my API and I hit the limit of requests frequently

Comment: You have an api key? Did you obtain it from Google developer console? There is an option in there to limit IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [authentication to Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/auth) can be done with two main methods:

- **Using a service account:** the service account key can be downloaded as a JSON file, and only the people who own that file will be able to authorize their requests against your API.
- **Using an API key:** it is a simple encrypted string that can be used for authentication when calling certain Google Cloud APIs. When using this method, you should follow the [best practices](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490), which include the method you ask for in your question, restricting API key usage by IP address. You can do that following the guide in this [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key), which consists in:

  1. Go to the **[Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?_ga=2.187348584.1553621033.1515398672-68002282.1512982995&_gac=1.237757876.1515083157.EAIaIQobChMIgrzww9y-2AIVQ5UbCh0IfgAtEAAYASAAEgJj7vD_BwE)** inside the APIs & Services tab in your Console.
  2. Select the **Create credentials** drop-down menu and then on **API key**.
     [image: Step 2]
  3. In the pop up menu that will appear, click on **Restrict key**.
     [image: Step 3]
  4. Choose the **IP addresses** option and type the IP address you want to allow. Then save.
     [image: Step 4]
     Then you will be able to use that API key as a secure method for accepting requests only from your server.